# Magento 1.7 product re-import issue

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to re-import a simple product file in magento 1.7 after deleting these products. File is successfully importing but products are not visible in manage products page even after re-indexing

Comment: Have you also checked in database table there is product entry or not.

Comment: I have checked in /public_html/var/importexport/catalog_product,csv and the file is updated with these products. I am not sure about database table. Can you help where I can check database table? Thanks.

Comment: Check database table "catalog_product_entity" please check there is new record entry.

Comment: There is no record entry of these products

Comment: Please check at magentoroot/var/log/*.log file error is any error written there.

Comment: There is no error. Log file has not recorded any error.

Answer (score 0):

If import is succesful and your products are showing in the database but not in the backend, make sure that all required attributes are set.

After the import you can do the following:

Go to `catalog -> manage products`. Your current url will look like:

`[yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/[your_key]/`

Change this url to `[yoursite.com]/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[product_id]/key/[your_key]/`

You can find the product ids in the database. When you enter this url, you can edit the product and check/edit product attributes, like tax class, status, etc and make sure alle required attributes are set.